# Opposite of dropna() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` that I want to separate into observations for which there are no missing values and observations with missing values. I can use `dropna()` to get rows without missing values. Is there any analog to get rows with missing values?

```
#Example DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,np.nan,3,4,5],'col2': [6,7,np.nan,9,10],})

#Get observations without missing values
df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check `null` by row and filter with boolean indexing:

```
df[df.isnull().any(1)]

#  col1 col2
#1  NaN  7.0
#2  3.0  NaN
```

Comment: Or if you were super concerned about performance, `df[np.isnan(df.values).any(1)]` - the difference in `any`'s performance between an ndarray and a DataFrame has always seemed noticeable to me.

Answer (score 9):

`~` = ***Opposite***  :-)

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.dropna().index)]

Out[234]: 
   col1  col2
1   NaN   7.0
2   3.0   NaN
```

Or

```
df.loc[df.index.difference(df.dropna().index)]
Out[235]: 
   col1  col2
1   NaN   7.0
2   3.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following expression as the opposite of dropna.  In this case, it keeps rows based on the specified column that are null.  Anything with a value is not kept.

```
csv_df = csv_df.loc[~csv_df['Column_name'].notna(), :]
```