# Grouping and Splitting Data from a single column of a Pandas Dataframe Based on datatype (float,Nan,string)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, xlsx

Based on my specific issue I tried to create a small reproducible example without coming to a point.
It is attached at the end of the question.

I am currently reading 27 excel files.

All formatted in the same way (apparently seems that all the column are consistent each other).

I am appending this data in a single DataFrame composed by 9828 rows and three columns.

**One column called "Target" should be composed only by float or interger.**

Actually cells that compose Target column are read as:

1. Float
2. In only one case an empty cell is read as a string
3. In other cases empty cells are considered `None`

In order to understand which specific Column DataFrame row contains float/none/string I created a very inefficient way to check and split the dataframe based on the datatype

```
    dt_t is a dataframe with 3 columns one of this is called Target
    This column is composed by 9398 non-null object. 
    The other two by 9828 non-null object.

    df_string=pd.DataFrame()
    df_float=pd.DataFrame()
    df_null=pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(len(df_t.Target)):
      if type(df_t.Target.loc[i])==str:
         df_string=df_string.append(df_t.loc[i])
      if type(df_t.Target.loc[i])==int or type(df_t.Target.loc[i])==float:
          df_float=df_float.append(df_t.loc[i])
      else: 
          df_null=df_null.append(df_t.loc[i])
```

***I can't understand why:***

1. There is a duplicate. `df_string` and `df_null` contain the same value
2. In the float dataframe I still have `nan` values

**My expected output** was to see

1. Only float and int in one dataframe
2. Only nan in df_null
3. Only string in df_string dataframe

The most elegant way to extract nan values was [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46626796/6290211) but I think my issue is slightly different

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.dropna().index)]
```

I tried also to find some resources and read the documentation to understand why [`pd.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) has this behaviour, but I didn't find anything useful.

Here the code I tried to create for a reproducible question (but is not working):

```
    a=pd.Series(np.random.uniform(1.00,100.00,9000))
    b=np.empty(400)
    b=pd.Series(np.full_like(b,np.nan))
    c=pd.Series('None')
    start_dict={"Target":[0,2,3.5] }
    df_t=pd.DataFrame(start_dict)
    df_t=pd.concat([df_t,a],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
    df_t=pd.concat([df_t,b],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
    df_t=pd.concat([df_t,c],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
```

Here my actual Output when I print  `df_string` and `df_null`:

[image]

Here in yellow the reference cell in the  `xlsx` file:

[image]

Comment: Always set seed for random data, `np.random.seed(###)`, so values are reproducible.

Comment: Can't quite see what you mean in reproducible example. Please show your issue claimed with *there is a duplicate. `df_float` and `df_null` contain the same value*.

Comment: @Parfait 100% agree with the seed my mistake because my example was not working. What I should not understand was why the cell read as string in this categorization example was counted also in the `df_null` `if`  cycle. I supposed that should be counted only in the `df_string`

Comment: Please show rather than tell this special string counted in both. NaNs can be of *any* type.

Comment: @Parfait I made a mistake typing my question. I wrote `df_float` but I actually I would type `df_string.` This mistake was only in my question not in the code. I am very desolated and sorry about this I also read again the question before posting. Hope that now could be better

Comment: I still do not understand your problem. A `NaN` can exist in *any* column including string, so yes row can appear in both *df_string* and *df_null*.

Comment: @Parfait Because is the same cell that is computed two times, one as Nan and one as a string. My goal was to analyze a specific column, so the output should be unique, not in different counters. Make sense that NaN can exist in any column, but I would read one column and identify each cell data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type is not safe to use. Since columns have mixed types pandas will use the `object` type for all rows. However, you can do this in another way.

First create the empty DataFrames:

```
df_string = pd.DataFrame()
df_float = pd.DataFrame()
df_null = pd.DataFrame()
```

Now you need to create a function that categorizes your original DataFrame. A slightly modified version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float) should do:

```
def categorize(x):
    if x.isna():
        df_null = df_null.append([x]) # append does not change the original df
        return
    try:
        float(x)
    except ValueError:
        df_string = df_string.append([x])
    else:
        df_float = df_float.append([x])
```

Now all you have to do is `apply` the function to the `Target` column.

```
df['Target'].apply(lambda x: categorize(x), axis=1)
```